# Getting server's DN from server-side certs in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, pki

I am running a NodeJS https webserver on an intranet, which makes calls to other secured webservers using REST. Because one of the sites I need to communicate with requires the server's DN to be appended to the proxied entities/issuers chain when communicating with it, I need to get the Distinguished Name (DN) of the server from its certificates.

I know that normally this is handled behind the scenes by the https.get() call, but is there a way to get the DN before making the get() call?

Answer (score 0):

Edward,

You can load the certificate directly using PKIjs (https://pkijs.org) and then decode the certificate extracting the DN.

You can see an example of decoding the certificate with this library here - https://pkijs.org/examples/X509_cert_complex_example.html